# Sql query searching for the first three letters

Tags: sql, hibernate

My Sql query is not correct. I want to create a query that searches for companies whose first three characters are equal to the given parameter

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="Company.retrieveNameCompanyForFirstThreeChar",
    query =" SELECT SUBSTRING(company_name, 1, 3) AS keyword from companies 
    WHERE = :KEYWORD",
    resultClass = Company.class
)
```

My error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
>   could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

Comment: is this ok? `WHERE = :KEYWORD`? Should there be something after  `WHERE` before `=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT company_name
FROM companies 
WHERE SUBSTRING(company_name FROM 1 FOR 3) = :KEYWORD;
```

You may want to add a TRIM() function around "company_name" in case of blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There is subtring function provided by mysql.

```
SELECT company_name FROM companies WHERE SUBSTRING(company_name FROM 1 FOR 3) = :KEYWORD;
```